# Event Grid - Logic Apps - Could Not Retrieve Values

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I'm attempting to work through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app)

I created service principal as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal)

Granted the service principal Contributor on the **subscription**.

When I go to the Logic app, the connection using the service principal succeeds, I

1. select "When a resource event occurs"
2. select my subscription
3. select GridTopics for resource type
4. the resource name pull down errors out "Could Not Retrieve Values"

Comment: Have you created a topic 1st ?

Comment: Yes, I created an Event Grid Top before all of this.   My service principal has Contributor access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I just need to give Azure time to connect the dots....